# How can I remove compression artifacts from an image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I got a picture where there is some noise in it. To remove that I have to redraw it with pen because all I want is a crystal clear image. Is there any simple way to do it? I not, what steps would you take?

before:

[image]

after

[image]

Comment: There is no general procedure for removing compression artifacts. Its allways a manual case by case job. If it were possible then the image reader would do so for you.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you already have artefacts in your before image.

In Photoshop, when you scale up that type of image with a lot of flat solid colors, use the Nearest neighbor setting. But that won't help if the source image already has artefacts.

[image: Nearest neighbor setting]

To fix your original image, you can use try Filter > Noise > Reduce noise, click Remove JPG artefacts and play around with the settings to see if you get any better results.

For your specific image, you might also want to try a blur such as Surface blur. Also, make sure you don't save as a JPG to avoid further compression. Depending on what you want to do with this, keep a PSD and a PNG.

Comment: I am trying noise reduction.. but still not successful

Comment: I've edited my answer, try surface blur (Filters>Blur>Surface blur) that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

For a geometrical source like the one given in the example probably the cleanest results can be obtained by tracing the image to vector graphics.

To make this easier we may divide the source image to it's symmetrical sub-parts (we then only have to trace a single tile):

[image]

<sup>Part of example image manually traced to a vector graphic</sup>

We can then stitch the tiles together by copy & paste, and by mirroring the tiles:

[image]

<sup>Tiles stitched together. White lines between tiles are for illustration only</sup>

Vector graphics will have no compression artifacts and can be scaled to any desired size.

Comment: I already do that.. but in some cases, the images are  not so geometric.